# Do some (prestige?) accents swap /v/ or /f/ for /w/?

Tags: accent

I have only a layman's grasp of phonology and a poor ear to boot, but it seems to me that for many Chinese whom I am told have markedly standard pronunciation, /w/ and some type of labiodental fricative are interchangeable. For instance, listen to Echo's 认为 near the end of this episode of Popup Chinese (from about 7:20 onward): http://data.popupchinese.com/778/elementary-it-happened-one-night-traditional.mp3

Am I the only one who hears this? Could these two phonemes be in free variation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mentioned this phenomenon in an answer to another post [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1094/characteristics-of-northern-and-southern-accents/1098#1098).  This sound, which is actually [ʋ] ([labiodental approximant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labiodental_approximant)), was also discussed in [this post in the Beijing Sounds blog](http://www.sinoglot.com/bjs/2008/10/the-humble-v-says-veng-veng/).  Being characteristic of the Tianjin region (in my experience anyway), it's not standard, but many people don't seem to notice anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the following references interesting:

1. Hu, Mingyang (胡明扬). 1991. [Beijinghua shengmu W de yinzhi](http://people.cohums.ohio-state.edu/chan9/articles/bjw-hu_utf8.htm) (北京话声母W音值) (Phonetic value of W initial in Beijing speech). In: *Yuyanxue Lunwen Xuan* (语言论文选) (Selected Writings in Linguistics). Beijing: Zhongguo Renmin Daxue Chubanshe. Pp. 244-245.
2. Shen, Jiong (沈炯). 1987. Beijinghua hekouhu ling shengmude yuyin fenqi (北京话合口呼零声母的语音分歧) (Phonetic differences of zero initial before finals beginning with u in the Beijing dialect.) *Zhongguo Yuwen* (中国语文) 5: 352-36. Transcribed [here](http://www.pkucn.com/viewthread.php?tid=36461).